# How to make ncurses display UTF-8 chars correctly in C?

Tags: c, linux, screen, ncurses

I have a program written in C using ncurses. It let user input and display it. It does not display correctly if user input utf8 chars.

I saved the chars user inputed to a file. And I `cat` this file directly in Shell, it display correctly.

I searched stackoverflow and google, and tried several methods, such as link with ncursesw, display incorrectly.

And I `ldd /usr/bin/screen`:`libncurses.so.5 => /usr/lib64/libncurses.so.5`

`screen` can display what user input correctly.

How to make ncurses display UTF-8 chars correctly ?

What is the general way to display UTF-8 chars in C using ncurses?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to have called `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");` (with a UTF-8 based locale configured) before initializing ncurses. You also need to make sure your ncurses is actually built with wide char support ("ncursesw") but on modern distros this is the default/only build.

Comment: Is there an easy way to tell if ncurses was built with wide char support?

Comment: @KdawgUD On Ubuntu, you can install the library with sudo apt-get install libncursesw5-dev. Use the ncursesw library when building, and include the ncursesw/curses.h library

Comment: As the maintainer [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50767405/why-wont-ncurses-output-all-the-foreign-characters-of-an-utf8-string#comment88545254_50767529) it might be better to use `setlocale(LC_ALL, "");`

Comment: @StefanSchmidt: I specifically **don't recommend** `setlocale(LC_ALL,"");` because it breaks parsing/emitting of floating point numbers and possibly other things. If you do it, you should follow up with `setlocale(LC_NUMERIC,"C");` to undo that part.

Answer (score 0):

```
#need these as well on top of installation and locate setting
#at least check locale
locale

locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
#vim ~/.bashrc # add 3 lines once ok and fix the profile
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export NCURSES_NO_UTF8_ACS=1
```