# ncurses - mvwprintw generates whitespace

Tags: c, whitespace, ncurses

I have a ncurses project, where I use mvwprintw to print a long string to a window.

```
mvwprintw(traceview_window_flatprofile, 1, 0, "%s", flatprofile_as_str());
```

the result looks like this:

```
  %       self    children             self    children
 time      time      time     calls    /call     /call  name
 39.86    886 µs       0 ns       32  27697 ns      0 ns  addr_translate [13]
 25.69    571 µs   1454 µs          1    571 µs   1454 µs  main [0]
  7.02    156 µs       0 ns        1    156 µs       0 ns  addr_fini [66]
  6.28    139 µs  55006 ns         1    139 µs  55006 ns  addr_init [2]
  3.83  85094 ns  21956 ns        2  42547 ns  10978 ns  flatprofile_snprintf [43]
  2.08  46150 ns      0 ns        1  46150 ns      0 ns  addr_read_symbol_table [3]
```

When I print the same string to stderr, using

```
fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", flatprofile_as_str());
```

the result looks like:

```
  %       self    children             self    children
 time      time      time     calls    /call     /call  name
 39.86    886 µs      0 ns       32  27697 ns      0 ns  addr_translate [13]
 25.69    571 µs   1454 µs        1    571 µs   1454 µs  main [0]
  7.02    156 µs      0 ns        1    156 µs      0 ns  addr_fini [66]
  6.28    139 µs  55006 ns        1    139 µs  55006 ns  addr_init [2]
  3.83  85094 ns  21956 ns        2  42547 ns  10978 ns  flatprofile_snprintf [43]
  2.08  46150 ns      0 ns        1  46150 ns      0 ns  addr_read_symbol_table [3]
```

Do you know what could cause this difference?

EDIT: in addition to the answer below, the following question solves a related issue.
[How to make ncurses display UTF-8 chars correctly in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922528/how-to-make-ncurses-display-utf-8-chars-correctly-in-c)

Comment: Is that happening also when you start printing at 0, 0 coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference seems to be caused by the special character **µ** i am not quite sure how you can fix it but you will probably have to adjust your `flatprofile_as_str()` function.

I remember having a similar problem with special chars from utf-8 and i solved it by using this function to count not the bytes but the actual lenght of a string:

```
int strlen_utf8(char *s) { 
   int i = 0, j = 0;
   while (s[i]) {
     if ((s[i] & 0xc0) != 0x80) j++;
     i++;
   }
   return j;
}
```

Comment: yes, you are right. replacing the µ with a u removes the issue.

Comment: NCurses and special chars aren't friends :-)